# Cuando las herramientas se seleccionan pierden la imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objeto, src

Cuando se hace click en las diferentes imágenes de las herramientas, las mismas deben desaparecer de la caja de herramientas para pasar a estar dentro de las herramientas seleccionadas, pasa que cuando se hace este proceso la imagen de la herramienta no es visible y la consola dice que no puede encontrarla.

```
var imagesDatabase = {
       selectedTool: 
document.getElementById(selectedTool).scr
  }
console.log(imagesDatabase[selectedTool]);
```

Al ejecutar estas líneas de código categoriza el objeto como ¨Undefined¨, obviamente, el resto del código para graficar las imágenes está dentro de la función pero en sí desde aquí se puede observar el problema

[image: Antes de seleccionar una herramienta]

[image: Después de ejecutar el código]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. Se requiere el código para saber como generas la Caja de Herramienta y desde luego tambien el código cuando la seleccionas (que realiza la acción que indicas); sin código te puedo comentar ¿que es **selectedTool** es un nombre de TAG (asumo `img`) `document.getElementById(selectedTool).scr` o un indice de array `imagesDatabase[selectedTool]`? ¿ademas `selectedTool` será/es numero o texto?

Comment: He publicado el código para que puedas revisar mejor

Comment: Saludos de nuevo; el código va como texto no como imagen; de momento te sugiero que el ' this'  lo cambies a 'this.id'. 'this'  es el objeto completo; en tu caso el `img` no corresponde a una posición de un arreglo, ni a un `id` ni tampoco a una propiedad de un objeto; por eso el `undefined`.